# Get Currency Code and Rate inside controller

Tags: magento2

How to get **Currency Code** & **Currency Rate** inside controller?
So that I can use it in my Ajax response and show it on the frontend.

**Update: Now I am getting CurrencySymbol(the symbol is not changing for each store view ) also CurrencyRate is empty by using the below code**

```
<?php
namespace Ishaq\CheckoutTotal\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
 
class Index extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_currency;
 
    public function __construct(
                                Context $context, 
                                PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
                                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                                \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency
                                
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_currency = $currency;
        
    }
 
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $data['getBaseCurrencyCode'] = $this->getBaseCurrencyCode();
        $data['getCurrentCurrencyCode'] = $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        $data['getDefaultCurrencyCode'] = $this->getDefaultCurrencyCode();
        $data['getCurrentCurrencySymbol'] = $this->getCurrentCurrencySymbol();
        $data['getCurrentCurrencyRate'] = $this->getCurrentCurrencyRate();
        $data['store_view'] = $this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode();
        
        
        var_dump($data); exit;
        
        $response = $this->resultFactory
            ->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
            ->setData($post);
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Get store base currency code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseCurrencyCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
    }
    
     /**
     * Get current store currency code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrentCurrencyCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    }    
    
    /**
     * Get default store currency code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDefaultCurrencyCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getDefaultCurrencyCode();
    }


    /**
     * Get current currency rate
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getCurrentCurrencyRate()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyRate();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get currency symbol for current locale and currency code
     *
     * @return string
     */    
    public function getCurrentCurrencySymbol()
    {
        return $this->_currency->getCurrencySymbol();
    }
    
    /* Get Store Name
       *
        * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\StoreManagerInterface
        */
       public function getStore() {
         $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
           $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
           return $storeManager->getStore();
       }
       
       
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` and `\Magento\Directory\Model\Currency` in your controller and get currency code and rate this way:

```php
<?php
namespace Ishaq\Module\Controller;

class YourController
{
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_currency;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_currency = $currency;
    }
    
        
    /**
     * Get store base currency code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseCurrencyCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
    }
    
     /**
     * Get current store currency code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrentCurrencyCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    }    
    
    /**
     * Get default store currency code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDefaultCurrencyCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getDefaultCurrencyCode();
    }


    /**
     * Get current currency rate
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getCurrentCurrencyRate()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyRate();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get currency symbol for current locale and currency code
     *
     * @return string
     */    
    public function getCurrentCurrencySymbol()
    {
        return $this->_currency->getCurrencySymbol();
    }
}
```

Reference: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-currency-data-code-rate-symbol-magento-2.html

Comment: I am able to get data but not as expected, I am changing store but getCurrentCurrencySymbol still remains the same.